# What is the cleanest way to initialize dynamic list in Python?

Tags: python

This is a question regarding best coding practices. Suppose I have to populate a list of unknown length; usually I just initialize the list with `myList = []`, but I feel like this is a poor way of doing this. I often end up with chunks of code that look like this:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []

for a,b,c in zip(x,y,z):
    list1.append(a)
    list2.append(b)
    list3.append(c)
```

I realize in the example you can initialize this lists to the correct length, in fact you can just use `x,y,z` as they are. My question is regarding a situation in which you don't necessarily know the length of the lists. In my opinion, having to use three lines to initialize this lists is clunky; what do you guys thing? Thanks for any input!

Comment: Why is that a poor thing to do? *Most* use of lists is to handle a variable number of items.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how many lists are being passed to `zip`?

Comment: No, I just used that as an example to illustrate how it requires three lines of code to initialize the lists. I understand lists are used to hold a variable number of items. I was wondering if there was a way to initialize them in a more clean manner.

Comment: `list1 = list(x)` etc?

Comment: ```lists = [[] for i in range(n_lists)]```

Comment: @chepner please re-read the question in its entirety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list of lists:

```
lol = [[], [], []]
for items in zip(x, y, z):
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        lol[i].append(item)
```

Comment: The point wasn't to solve the particular problem (as eeScott says in the question, he realizes he can just use `x, y, z`) but to show a pattern of dealing with multiple lists.

Comment: So your suggestion is just a list of lists? That's an interesting idea. I guess in the same manner you could do `a,b,c = [],[],[]`.

Comment: Yes, when you see the same operation being done to very similar objects under different names, the best solution is often to put them in a container of some sort so you can iterate over them and do the same thing to each within the loop. Another option is often to write a function to do the thing to them and pass each into the function, but that doesn't really apply in this case.

Answer (score 2):

No need for anything clever:

```
list1 = list(x)
list2 = list(y)
list3 = list(z)
```

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: Ah. What did you ask?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. This does the same thing as your current loop, only more clearly and more efficiently.

Comment: "I realize in the example you can initialize this lists to the correct length, in fact you can just use `x,y,z` as they are. My question is regarding a situation in which you don't necessarily know the length of the lists."

Comment: The length of `x`? or the length of `(x, y, z)`? i.e. there might not be 3

Comment: I just provided an example loop where I had to initialize 3 lists to populate them. Suppose the information is instead coming from user input where it's contained in a while loop and on each iteration the user is asked to input more data or exit the loop. Is there a more pythonic way to initialize these lists than to have to use a new line for each initialization that is of the form `newList = []`?